# Frames per second drops when game is minimized :(

Tags: flash, actionscript

In one of the newer flash player versions, adobe added a feature to the flash player that drops the frame rate of the swf to something like 2 FPS when it's minimized (ie. you switch tabs on your browser, you minimize your browser, etc).

I have made a multi-player game and this "feature" is causing a real headache.  Players are able to minimize their game and avoid dying (as their client is more or less paused while the other opponents continue playing).

Is there any way to get around this?  I can't see to find any documentation on how to turn this feature off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: or just rewrite the game so you're not depending on framerate for advancement. e.g. if any of the big shooter games depended on frame rates, then cheaters would simply run on a slow-old rig and force their framerate down.

Answer (score 1):

Your FPS/rendering pipeline should be isolated from the logic. There are many techniques to do this, but a simple is rather than fixing the FPS to a target rate and basing everything on that, check the time elapsed each cycle and perform the appropriate actions for the elapsed time.

Ideally of course you are running a multi-kernel app, but I'm not sure what capabilities you have available in a SWF plus it is easier to retro-fit this method to an existing system fixed to FPS rate.

You end up with stuff like this:

```
newX = oldX + (xSpeedPerSecond * secondsElapsed)
```

At least this is how we did it 17 years ago when I was a teenager...

Comment: Every language is different and flash/actionscript makes this a bit more difficult to understand. If you don't know the answer, don't answer a generic thing that does not help the OP.

Comment: It may seem that way when you first start programming, but once you've spent enough time and learn many different languages you'll start to see the same problems and patterns cut across many different languages and old patterns reappear in new technology arenas.

Comment: And who posts questions here ? Experts or beginners ? ;)
And i can tell you the flash/actionscript VM does some things in a weird way that is really specific and can't be known unless you thoroughly tested it, which is why your answer isn't really helpful in this case. You have to use an enterframe loop instead of a timer loop because timers really aren't reliable, which is pretty much different from every other languages / APIs i've used.

Comment: Nope, that will help, but the issue remains nevertheless. There are many similar systems to Flash actually. It is a pattern employed by systems that do not give you full control over the system and require you to execute your code and release without promising much in return. You need to ensure that your logic is not dependent on being executed at an interval when the system doesn't guarantee it. This pattern is utilized not only in games, but many other kinds of real-time systems as well. Sometimes even when you have full control you'll end up implementing one in your own sub-systems.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the time between each call to your function.
You can read a post i made on my website about this:
http://fabricebacquart.info/wordpress/?p=9

Basically, you just need to get the time and do your updates depending on this time. Like moving more or less depending on the time OR doing your updates routines more than once if needed.

Another way would be to override this behavior by setting the fps when the game isn't on focus but that would not be as reliable (see the corresponding events: Event.ACTIVATE and Event.DEACTIVATE and set stage.frameRate inside listener functions).

Comment: After all the discourse above (w/@Paul), I'm failing to see how your answer is fundamentally any different than what he was suggesting ;)